# Arch - How to See Open Apps

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I installed Discord. I got notifications even if I close it.
But I installed it in a Distrobox, so that I'm  using Arch via CLI.
My main system is Debian 12.4.

In case of needing to close background apps, I want to be able to first see them.

I open Discord via Arch Linux inside of Distrobox and when I close the app, I still get notifications.

I noticed my Debian 12 System Monitor shows Discord but it is running under Arch Linux.

I want to see the apps that runs still on background even if it is closed or minimized via CLI.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us (a lot) more context. You are using Arch, OK, what do you want to see? Where? What are "background apps"? Do you mean processes launched from the command line that you have sent to the background? Or minimized UI windows? Or something else? How is Discord relevant? Please [edit] and clarify what you need.

Comment: thanks. I edited it. is it ok now_?

Comment: Does ```top``` not accomplish what you need?

Comment: @BradenCarlson I think it works with System Monitor, thanks!